# GCP Terraform app_engine_standard_app_version internal error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform, task-queue

I have a GCP project utilizing a variety of services: GC Functions, Firestore, VPC Connector, Storage Buckets, App Engine, Compute Engine. I use Terraform for deployment.

I decided to add a message queue using Google Tasks Queue, and run it on App Engine.

There is a nodejs handler function I put into an `archive_file` before attempting to deploy it to App Engine. I do this for my GC Function and it works great.

From my research it looks like I need Terraform resource `app_engine_standard_app_version` or `app_engine_flexible_app_version` to run my handler function on my App Engine.

When I try to create this resource via `terraform apply` I get an error. Neither flexible or standard works.

**Code**

```
locals {
  timestamp = formatdate("YYMMDDhhmmss", timestamp())
}

resource "google_cloud_tasks_queue" "task-queue-b" {
  name     = "task-queue-b"
  location = "us-east1"

  rate_limits {
    max_concurrent_dispatches = 3
    max_dispatches_per_second = 2
  }

  retry_config {
    max_attempts       = 5
    max_retry_duration = "4s"
    max_backoff        = "3s"
    min_backoff        = "2s"
    max_doublings      = 1
  }
}

# Compress source code and make archive file
data "archive_file" "task-queue-source" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/task-queue-${local.timestamp}.zip"
  source_dir  = "../../../../queue/build/src" # index.js is here with handler func
}

# Create bucket that will host the source code
resource "google_storage_bucket" "task-queue-bucket" {
  name = "${var.project}-task-queue"
}

# Add source code zip to bucket
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "task-queue-zip" {
  # Append file MD5 to force bucket to be recreated
  name       = "task-queue-source.zip#${data.archive_file.task-queue-source.output_md5}"
  bucket     = google_storage_bucket.task-queue-bucket.name
  source     = data.archive_file.task-queue-source.output_path
  depends_on = [data.archive_file.task-queue-source]
}

resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "task-queue-flexible-v1" {
  project    = var.project
  service    = "default"
  version_id = "v1"
  runtime    = "nodejs14"

  entrypoint {
    shell = "node ./index.js"
  }

  deployment {
    zip {
      source_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/task-queue/${google_storage_bucket.task-queue-bucket.name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.task-queue-zip.name}"
    }
  }

  liveness_check {
    path = "."
  }

  readiness_check {
    path = "."
  }

  automatic_scaling {
    cool_down_period = "120s"
    cpu_utilization {
      target_utilization = 0.5
    }
  }

  delete_service_on_destroy = true
}
```

I receive the following errorr:

First issue: I don't think this is related...

```
2021-10-10T12:37:50.296-0400 [WARN]  Provider "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google\"]" produced an unexpected new value for module.analytics.google_cloudfunctions_function.analytics, but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
    The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
      - .source_archive_object: was cty.StringVal("source.zip#d8d06f1045f9387d72429479c37eb6b3"), but now cty.StringVal("source.zip")
module.analytics.google_cloudfunctions_function.analytics: Modifications complete after 2m16s [id=projects/<proj>/locations/us-east1/functions/analytics]
```

**Main error I can not for the life of me figure out:**

```
╷
│ Error: Error waiting to create FlexibleAppVersion: Error waiting for Creating FlexibleAppVersion: Error code 13, message: An internal error occurred.
│
│   with module.task-queue.google_app_engine_flexible_app_version.task-queue-flexible-v1,
│   on ..\..\modules\taskqueue\main.tf line 74, in resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "task-queue-flexible-v1":
│   74: resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "task-queue-flexible-v1" {
│
╵
2021-10-10T12:37:50.302-0400 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
```

**Questions**

1. Am I correct with my chosen resources to run my Task Queue handler function (nodejs express app)? Are there any resources I am missing? Do I need an actual `google_app_engine_application` TFE resource?
2. Any insight into this unhelpful error?

Thanks so much

Comment: I do not know the answer but I would solve this first: **it is using the legacy plugin SDK**. Google Cloud and HashiCorp are moving very fast with development. Whenever possible use the latest tools and providers.

Comment: I would like you to try two things : 1. The [App Engine flexible environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/app_engine_flexible_app_version) service account uses the member ID service-[YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER]@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com, you should have the App Engine Flexible Environment Service Agent role, which will be applied when the appengineflex.googleapis.com service is enabled.

Comment: 2. Can you migrate to [Terraform Plugin SDK](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/guides/v1-upgrade-guide.html)- standalone SDK and try if the issue still persists.